# How to restructure object of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

In my debugger this is how my log statement is printing my messages object:

```
self.messages = (
"<lean: 0x7fcf98665140, objectId: vglE1UJ5KI, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = Jj;\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = XvvxETqjph;\n    timestamp = \"1424991590106.210938\";\n}",
"<lean: 0x7fcf98667940, objectId: rgBFYBMKlU, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = \"test 3 from ian\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = Hoy7UjLzOh;\n    timestamp = \"1424631667110.638184\";\n}",
"<lean: 0x7fcf98667f30, objectId: hB5uhwsYsu, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = \"test 2 from user1\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = VQzxWbDnal;\n    timestamp = \"1424630904935.162109\";\n}",
"<lean: 0x7fcf986685b0, objectId: dOe2B9oq5b, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = \"test 1\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = XvvxETqjph;\n    timestamp = \"1424630808309.478027\";\n}"
)
```

1. what exactly is this? It looks like an object of dictionaries but the objectId and localId variables are outside of the curly braces so im not sure.
2. How do I restructure this so that I can have each individual dictionary by itself?

Im getting this data from my backend on parse.com:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

NSString *userId = [[PFUser currentUser] objectId];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"lean"];
[query whereKey:@"recipientId" equalTo:userId];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else {
        // We found messages!
        masterMessages = (NSDictionary *)objects;

        NSLog(@"self.messages = %@", masterMessages);



        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}];


}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code generating this log statement, as well as the code which generates these dictionaries.

Comment: What kind of object is it `lean`? Seems just that maybe someone overwrite `description` of your object.

Comment: You have an array of Parse objects.  Stupidly, Parse objects print like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a simple `NSArray` which contains objects of type named `lean`. you can get the needed object by its index

UPDATE:

I can't be sure of course. I have no idea about `lean`'s structure. But most likely it contains field (and I assume it must be a property) named `messageBody`. If it is really so then you can do the following:

```
NSMutableArray* messagesBySenderName = [NSMutableArray new];

for (id lean in objects)
{
  NSDictionary *messageBody = [lean valueForKeyPath:@"messageBody"];

  if ([lean[@"senderId"] isEqualToString:@"Hoy7UjLzOh"])
  {
    [messagesBySenderName addObject:messageBody];
  } 
}
```

Again - it is only an assumption. In no case I can guarantee it will work

Comment: what if I want to get out the messagebody for objects who's senderName = Hoy7UjLzOh?

Comment: Thank you but its not working.                                                                         2015-03-14 17:14:21.572 lean_tabbed_v4[49324:1512729] -[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbbb272fe60

Comment: This answer is well meaning, and partly correct, but not right.  your find results in an array of PFObjects.  I'll type up a quick answer now.

Comment: it works after changing that so go ahead and update your answer and i'll give this one to you if danh doesnt have a better answer from using the PFObject class.  Thanks Andrey!

Comment: It's a array of Parse objects.  The type they represent is "lean", but you have to use Parse interfaces to access them.

Comment: I have edited my answer but obviously dahn has much more comprehension on the topic

Answer (score 1):

They are `PFObject`s (from the parse.com framework), and PFObject implements `description` in this particular way.  PFObjects implement a dictionary-like interface that is [fully described here](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html).

With due respect to others, it is overly general to type them as `id`, and to use KVO to access their properties.  Moreover, `messageBody` appears to be a column of type string.  Treating as a dictionary will be unproductive.

PFObjects should be treated this way:

```
for (PFObject *pfObject in objects) {
    NSString *objectId = [pfObject objectId];
    NSDate *createdAt = [pfObject createdAt];
    NSString *messageBody = [pfObject objectForKey:@"messageBody"];
    NSString *senderId = [pfObject objectForKey:@"senderId"];
    // and so on
    NSLog(@"This object has id %@ created at %@, senderId %@", objectId, createdAt, senderId);
}
```

I'm aware of [your other recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050857/how-to-get-object-by-key-and-value) regarding how to derive and array of senderIds from this array.  Extracting senderId ought to be obvious from this code, but (a) you probably don't need a new array based on your UI need (a table of conversations), and (b) I think you're actually looking for senderName, and that might mean a substantial change to how you've implemented relationships between parse objects.

I'll try to answer further over on that other question, but this one is clearly related.

Comment: check out my updated question for a picture of the table

Comment: Got it.  As I suspected, not quite what you need to achieve the UI goal.  I'll elaborate on the other post.