# How to restructure array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform, nsdictionary

I'm querying an object of type NSArray called messages from my backend on parse.com that looks like this:

```
 self.messages = (
"<lean: 0x7fcf98665140, objectId: vglE1UJ5KI, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = Jj;\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = XvvxETqjph;\n    timestamp = \"1424991590106.210938\";\n}",
"<lean: 0x7fcf98667940, objectId: rgBFYBMKlU, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = \"test 3 from ian\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = Hoy7UjLzOh;\n    timestamp = \"1424631667110.638184\";\n}",
"<lean: 0x7fcf98667f30, objectId: hB5uhwsYsu, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = \"test 2 from user1\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = VQzxWbDnal;\n    timestamp = \"1424630904935.162109\";\n}",
"<lean: 0x7fcf986685b0, objectId: dOe2B9oq5b, localId: (null)> {\n    messageBody = \"test 1\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = XvvxETqjph;\n    timestamp = \"1424630808309.478027\";\n}"
)
```

So its basically an array of dictionary objects.  How do I reformat this as a normal array of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
self.messages = (
"{\n objectId: vglE1UJ5KI;\n    messageBody = Jj;\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = XvvxETqjph;\n    timestamp = \"1424991590106.210938\";\n}",
"{\n objectId: rgBFYBMKlU;\n    messageBody = \"test 3 from ian\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = Hoy7UjLzOh;\n    timestamp = \"1424631667110.638184\";\n}",
"{\n objectId: hB5uhwsYsu;\n    messageBody = \"test 2 from user1\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = VQzxWbDnal;\n    timestamp = \"1424630904935.162109\";\n}",
"{\n objectId: dOe2B9oq5b;\n    messageBody = \"test 1\";\n    recipientId = XvvxETqjph;\n    senderId = XvvxETqjph;\n    timestamp = \"1424630808309.478027\";\n}"
)
```

Comment: We're getting to be old friends on this topic ( :-) ).  I think I answered a form of this question correctly here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053822/how-to-restructure-object-of-nsdictionaries/29054387#29054387, and was a little surprised that you didn't see it that way.  Perhaps it's because uncertainty about the topic persists.  Hopefully my answer below will better explain.

Comment: No, it's not "basically an array of dictionary objects." It's an array of PFObjects, where a PFObject is a custom object that implements some dictionary-like methods, and has a description method that outputs information that sort of looks like a dictionary. When you log an object and display it using the "%@" format specifier, it calls the object's `description` method, and that's what you see. The output of the `description` method may or may not reflect the internal structure of the object being described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PFObject returned from parse is very much like a dictionary, insofar as it responds to `allKeys` and `objectForKey:` and `setObject:forKey:`, and so on.  I've seen several questioners on SO confused by the way PFObject implements `description` and therefore how it prints on the console, making it look less like a dictionary than it perhaps should.

Anyway, if for some reason one really must have an NSArray of NSDictionaries, rather than an NSArray of dictionary-like objects, then they could employ code like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromPFObject:(PFObject *)pfObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *key in [pfObject allKeys]) {
        dictionary[key] = [pfObject objectForKey:key];
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

... and call it from a find completion block like this:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (PFObject *pfObject in objects) {
            [array addObject:[self dictionaryFromPFObject:pfObject]];
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks danh.  Im actually just using parse.com for prototyping before i went to aws and i didnt really want to mess with parse but i'll take this approach